# Clang: Promoting all Warnings to Errors Except for …

Tags: clang, compiler-flags

In the project I currently am — and probably will for some time be — working on, we have decided to use the `-Werror` flag, as our previous “No warnings!” policy did not work out as intended.

This, however, imposes a certain problem:

API can no longer be marked as deprecated in a way that a) is flagged by the normal build toolchain, and b) doesn’t break the build.

So I guess the question boils down to:

**Is there a flag like `-Werror-no-${something_I_dont_want_to_promote_to_an_error}`?**

I found `#pragma clang diagnostic error` to *almost* achieve what I want — except that I fail to catch **all** the warnings that are enabled *implicitly* by the compiler…

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[From the manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages):

> `-Wno-error=foo`: Turn warning "foo" into a warning even if `-Werror` is specified.

Comment: Sometimes I have trouble finding the correct clang docs in a reasonable amount of time.  The manual link you provided is perfect for viewing all options regarding warning/error diagnostics, thank you for that.